# Angular Unit Tests Property 'toBeTruthy' does not exist on type 'Assertion'

Tags: angular, jasmine

Currently in a project Ive been assigned to there is an issue with VSCode not being able to determine the properties for the Jasmine assertions.  The tests run successfully, but intellisense in VSCode cannot determine the package.  This project has cypress configured along side jasmine, but I dont see any conflicts in the tsconfig.spec.json.
[image]

[image]

Comment: Please give a [mre], **as text**.

Comment: Hi there. What is your Cypress version? I faced a similar issue and installed a previous Cypress version using `ng add @cypress/schematic@2.0.0` and then added `./cypress.config.ts` to the `tsconfig.exclude` property like so: 

`"exclude": ["./cypress.config.ts"]`
Here is the cypress issue on Github: 
https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/22059#issuecomment-1148921141

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I was able to follow @aghwotu recommendation and added the below to my tsconfig.json in my root.  This created other issues, but fixed my issue with VSCode not finding the jasmine Assertions.

```
"exclude": ["cypress.config.ts"],
"files": ["cypress.config.ts"]
```

Comment: What "other issues"?

Comment: In a more complex project, you might need to also exclude cypress packages like badeball as well. So this is just a general answer to what can be a further problem down the road with the more cypress packages that are installed.

Answer (score 4):

I encountered the same problem today. I know the problem is already a year old, but perhaps the answer will help someone else who also runs into this.

I added the following to my `tsconfig.json`:

```
  "exclude": [
    "cypress/**/*.ts",
    "cypress.config.ts"
  ]
```

And I changed my `cypress/tsconfig.json`, which extends the `tsconfig.json`, to:

```
  "include": [
    "**/*.ts",
    "../cypress.config.ts"
  ],
  "exclude": []
```

This solved my issues with types and functions not being recognized in my .spec files and also kept my Cypress e2e tests running.

I hope this still helps you or someone else.