# Unit test passing on local but failing on jenkins with error TS2339: Property 'toBeTruthy' does not exist on type 'Assertion'

Tags: angular, typescript, unit-testing, jenkins, jasmine

I am working on a project with angular. I recently had a problem. When I run 'npm run test' on local, my test are passing and everything is good.

```
 it('should create', () => {
expect(component).toBeTruthy();});
```

But when I push my changes on Bitbucket, my build fails with jenkins.

```
    project@0.0.0 swb:test

[2024-01-23T15:09:14.375Z] > npm run test:ci

[2024-01-23T15:09:14.375Z] 

[2024-01-23T15:09:14.870Z] 

[2024-01-23T15:09:14.870Z] > project@0.0.0 test:ci

[2024-01-23T15:09:14.870Z] > ng test --watch false --code-coverage --browsers ChromeHeadlessForDocker --progress false

[2024-01-23T15:09:14.870Z] 

[2024-01-23T15:09:30.458Z] 

[2024-01-23T15:09:30.458Z] START:

[2024-01-23T15:09:30.458Z] 

[2024-01-23T15:09:30.458Z] Error: error TS2688: Cannot find type definition file for 'jest'.

[2024-01-23T15:09:30.458Z]   The file is in the program because:

[2024-01-23T15:09:30.458Z]     Entry point of type library 'jest' specified in compilerOptions

[2024-01-23T15:09:30.458Z] 

[2024-01-23T15:09:30.458Z] 

[2024-01-23T15:09:30.458Z] Error: src/app/footer/footer.component.spec.ts:22:23 - error TS2339: Property 'toBeTruthy' does not exist on type 'Assertion'.

[2024-01-23T15:09:30.458Z] 

[2024-01-23T15:09:30.458Z] 22     expect(component).toBeTruthy();

[2024-01-23T15:09:30.458Z]                          ~~~~~~~~~~

[2024-01-23T15:09:30.458Z] 

[2024-01-23T15:09:30.458Z] 

[2024-01-23T15:09:30.458Z] Error: src/app/header/header.component.spec.ts:22:23 - error TS2339: Property 'toBeTruthy' does not exist on type 'Assertion'.

[2024-01-23T15:09:30.458Z] 

[2024-01-23T15:09:30.458Z] 22     expect(component).toBeTruthy();

[2024-01-23T15:09:30.458Z]                          ~~~~~~~~~~

[2024-01-23T15:09:30.458Z] 

[2024-01-23T15:09:30.458Z] 

[2024-01-23T15:09:30.458Z] 

[2024-01-23T15:09:30.458Z] 23 01 2024 15:09:28.631:INFO [karma-server]: Karma v6.4.2 server started at http://localhost:9876/

[2024-01-23T15:09:30.458Z] 23 01 2024 15:09:28.633:INFO [launcher]: Launching browsers ChromeHeadlessForDocker with concurrency unlimited

[2024-01-23T15:09:30.458Z] 23 01 2024 15:09:28.633:ERROR [karma-server]: Error: Found 1 load error

[2024-01-23T15:09:30.458Z]     at Server.<anonymous> (/home/jenkins/workspace/UI_insurance-release-viewer_PR-4/node_modules/karma/lib/server.js:243:26)

[2024-01-23T15:09:30.458Z]     at Object.onceWrapper (node:events:628:28)

[2024-01-23T15:09:30.458Z]     at Server.emit (node:events:526:35)

[2024-01-23T15:09:30.458Z]     at emitListeningNT (node:net:1906:10)

[2024-01-23T15:09:30.458Z]     at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:81:21)

script returned exit code 1
```

Why is it passing on local but failing on jenkins ?
How can I fix this error ?
Please help me, I didn't find a solution and it is starting to be very annoying. :(
Ps: I got the same error on local but I fixed it thanks to this : [Angular Unit Tests Property 'toBeTruthy' does not exist on type 'Assertion'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74827556/angular-unit-tests-property-tobetruthy-does-not-exist-on-type-assertion)

I tried every solution I found on stack overflow! I tried to check their is a problem with docker, I also checked the jenkinsfile I also didn't find anything strange or that can cause a problem. I checked if their is a conflict between the versions I am using on local and the one I am using on jenkins and ended up doing this modification :

```
npm_nodejs_version: 20.8.1
npm_version: 10.1.0
```

Comment: Yes I have tried it but it still fails on jenkins :(

Comment: possible cause is dependency on jenkins is installed different version as your local. Please make sure your project has `package-lock.json` which used to lock dependencies version and commit it to repo.  With that, dependencies version will be consistent， regardless `npm ci` run on anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

I finally find the solution ! I had the same code that was passing on another branch so I executed this command :

```
git diff --name-only the-passed-branch..the-failing-branch
```

which gave me the list of the files name that were different and I checked each one of them to edit the difference.

I also edited the node and npm versions to those versions:

```
npm_nodejs_version: 16.13.0
npm_version: 6
```

PS: their is another solution which is to rebase the passing branch on the failed one.